# How to verify if a windows service is installed and running using the batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-services

I would like to use a batch file to check if the service is installed and if so, if it is running, then install or run it as necessary, but I'm not sure how to put it all together. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

```
sc query service_name >nul 2>nul|find /i "running" &&(
   echo service is not running
)||(
  echo service running
)

sc query service_name >nul 2>nul|find /i "1060" &&(
   echo service is not installed
)||(
  echo service installed
)
```